# How can I migrate QB ASP.NET ASMX Web Service code to a SoapCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, asmx, qbxml, soapcore

Good evening, everyone. I was given a task that I am not sure if it is possible to complete.

There a [QuickBooks Web Service tool](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK_Samples/tree/master/qbdt/c-sharp/qbXML/WCWebService) that works perfectly, but unfortunately that tool is written in .NET Framework that is an outdated technology and, thus, difficult to integrate with the .NET Core tools.

My task was to convert this web service to a .NET Core.

I did discover a [tool called SoapCore](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3709201/how-to-create-soap-services-in-aspnet-core.html#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20you%20can%20also,NET%20Core%20application.) that is very intuitive, but I don't think it works.

The way it works when I run its ASMX, in the browser it opens the WSDL just like here on a screenshot

[image]

But when I run the original QuickBooks web service, it presents me with the user interface to interact with the Web Service methods just like here on a screenshot

[image]

I suspect that this original Web Service is web method-based, something I am not sure how to implement in the SoapCore, just in case here is the [link](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK_Samples/blob/master/qbdt/c-sharp/qbXML/WCWebService/App_Code/WCWebService.asmx.cs) to the Web Service ASMX codebehind to get all the details about all methods it exposes

Thus, the question is if it is even possible to migrate web method based ASP.NET ASMX Web Service, just like in the example I gave earlier, to a SoapCore. Should I explore other tools such as the [WCF Web Service Reference Provider Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Basically I would like to host ASMX SOAP based Web Service using the .NET Core technology in a way for it to expose all its methods via the user interface just like in [this example](https://test.developer.intuit.com/qbwc/troubleshootwebserviceFS/service.asmx)

Please some one point me in a right direction

Thank you in advance!